# Why put null-safety twice in a List of values

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose defining two lists:

```
List<MediaItem?> playlist = [];    
List<Item> items = [Item(data:'vasya')];
```

and two models:

```
class MediaItem {
  final String id;
  
  MediaItem({
    required this.id
  });
}

class Item {
  final String data;
  
  Item({
    required this.data,
  });
  
  MediaItem toMediaItem() => MediaItem(
    id: data,
  );
}
```

Then populating first list like this:

```
playlist = items.map(
  (el) => el.toMediaItem()
).toList();
```

Then if I try to change element in a list:

```
playlist[0] = null;
```

IDE/DartPad thinks it's fine, but after running, Dart throws an error: `Uncaught Error: TypeError: null: type 'JSNull' is not a subtype of type 'MediaItem'`
It works only when null-safety question mark is added `toMediaItem()` method:

```
MediaItem? toMediaItem() => MediaItem(
  id: data,
);
```

How so? I thought defining a `List<MediaItem?>` should be sufficient to change value to null at anytime...

DartPad sample: https://dartpad.dev/?id=592167a9f6e1a08344a51800c67887d3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you end up creating a new list object here:

```dart
playlist = items.map(
  (el) => el.toMediaItem()
).toList();
```

Yes, Dart know the type of your variable but in this case, it takes the type of the returned value of `map()` and uses that to determine the type of the created list. In this case, you end up with a `List<MediaItem>` object which can be assigned to a `List<MediaItem?>` variable without issue.

If you instead uses the already created `playlist` list:

```
playlist.addAll(items.map((el) => el.toMediaItem()));
```

Then you don't get hit by this issue. Alternative you can also do to tell Dart what exact type you want the `map()` to return:

```dart
playlist = items.map<MediaItem?>((el) => el.toMediaItem()).toList();
```

**EDIT:**

You can also do:

```dart
playlist = [for (final el in items) el.toMediaItem()];
```

Where Dart will look at the type of the variable and use that to determine which type it should create the list for.

Comment: _"it takes the type of the returned value of map() and uses that to determine the type of the created list"_ This could lead into further question: Why can't we assign a `List<SomeOtherType>` though? **EDIT:** I just confirmed it has to be the same class or the subclass (In this case, `MediaItem` is a subclass of `MediaItem?`)